# Couldn't save data to local storage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm building an e-commerce with React, in which, there is a dropdown menu that has different currencies. The currencies are coming from a GraphQL endpoint that has all the info. When the user choose a currency, it changes the listed prices. That is implemented by a contexts and I consume that context in the currency selector component. All of this works fine, however, when I start the web from the very beginning, nothing shows up as there is no currency saved as a default. I'm trying to save the first currency in the dropdown menu to the local storage and set it to the context but nothing of this worked for me. Please let me know what do you recommend to do that?

I will attach my code below for the currency selector component and the currency context.

**CurrencyContext.js**

```
    export const CurrencyContext = createContext()

class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {

    state = {selectedCurrency: 'uiu'}
    setCurrency = (c)=>{
        this.setState({selectedCurrency: c})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CurrencyContext.Provider value={{...this.state, setCurrency: this.setCurrency}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CurrencyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default CurrencyContextProvider;
```

**CurrencySelector.js**

```
    export class CurrencySelector extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { currencies: [] }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let currencies = (await this.getCurrencies()).data.currencies
        this.setState({ currencies:currencies } )
    }

    async getCurrencies(){
        return await fetchTheQuery( `query{ currencies }` )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CurrencyContext.Consumer>
                {(currencyContext) => {
                    const {setCurrency} =currencyContext
                    return(
                        <select name="currency-selector"
                                onChange={event => {
                                        setCurrency(event.target.value)
                                        localStorage.setItem("currency", event.target.value)
                                }}>
                            {this.state.currencies.map(
                                (currency, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <option value={currency}>
                                            {currency}
                                        </option>
                                    )
                                }
                            )}
                        </select>
                    )
                }}
            </CurrencyContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andy could you please show me?

Comment: @Andy btw, I'm using a class component idk if it works with it or not

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I completely missed that.

Comment: where are you fetching the state from localstorage ?

Comment: @programoholic data is fetched under `getCurrencies()` in `CurrencySelector.js`

Comment: @programoholic Did you get my issue?

Comment: You're calling grapQL api in the getacurrency method. Where is localstorage.getItem ?

Comment: @programoholic I tried to do this and it didn't work, so I cleared it. I'm looking to save the default currency using another method instead of local storage. I want to save it in the context. The context works fine, but there is no default currency saved at the very beginning. Please let me know if something isn't clear so I can clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the function in `onChange` is not running currently?

Maybe you can isolate the function you pass into `onChange` to a class function called `handleChange`.

Comment: `onChange` is running perfectly. My problem is with storing a default currency to the context. So, when you start the web at the very beginning a default currency must show up on the screen. Let me know if something isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you problem correctly , you need to load default value in the select box before the API returns the data. You also want to keep the previous value chose by user as the selected value when the response is recieved by the `GraphQL` API. Here is what you can do :
In the `contextProvider` load the default value from localStorage as follows :

```
function getDefaultValue() {
  const currency = localStorage.getItem('currency');
  return currency ? currency : 'USD';
}
const defaultVal = getDefaultValue(); //Insert the default value here.
export const CurrencyContext = createContext();
class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedCurrency: defaultVal }; // initial value in state
    this.setCurrency = this.setCurrency.bind(this);
  }
... rest of the code
```

Now the consumer will receive `selectedCurrency` with the default value populated from the `localStorage`.

Now In consumer, you need to check and toggle b/w options  :

```
      {currencies.length
        ? currencies.map((currency, index) => {
            return <option value={currency}>{currency}</option>;
          })
        : // render the default currency from context when currency is not loaded
          [selectedCurrency].map((currency, index) => {
            return <option value={currency}>{currency}</option>;
          })}
```

Also you need to set the `value` prop on select with `selectedCurrency`.

Here is the Working example : [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qrpdtr?file=src/App.js)

P.S : You should consider moving the entire code to functional components and utilise `useContext` hook.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the default currency must be the first currency in the array that I get from the endpoint

Comment: do you get it in the response  ?

Comment: Yes I get all the currencies from the response of the endpoint

Comment: did you check the example ?

Comment: the select box will be selected with the default value.

Comment: Yes I checked the example, but this is not what I want. I want to store the first index currency array to the context in `selectedCurrency` by default

Comment: for the very first time, you won't be having anything in the localstorage or in the component unless you make the API call and get the response. So you need to Hard code it. If you want to set it after the response is received from the API , how hard for you is to call localStorage.setItem next to line when you receive the response ?

Comment: your question says something else and you're commenting something else

Comment: I already did that, but how can I set that data to the context? I did that in `componentDidMount` but that was after posting my question. In the context under `selectedCurrency` I put `selectedCurrency: localStorage.getItem("currency")` but the default currency didn't show up on the screen. The reason why is that the context executes before all the components.

Comment: for the first time render it will show as blank because nothing is loaded yet in the app. then you can call  `context.setCurrency` after the getting the data from the API. I've updated the stackblitz

Comment: I just called that in `componentDidMount()` and I got this error. `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _contexts_CurrencyContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.CurrencyContext.Consumer.setCurrency is not a function
`

Comment: Check that link carefully it is working. I can't spoon feed . sorry